# How I can change <input>'s CSS properties, when its validate the passwords?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating registration form, and want to before clicking on submit button to change `<input>`'s CSS properties when the passwords don't match (change background color).

```
if ($_POST["pass"] != $_POST["pass_again"]){
    $message = "Passwords don't match";
    echo ('
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            document.getElementById("pass_again").background-color = "red";
        </script>
    ');
}
```

Comment: You'd want to do this at the client level first and then at the server level.

Comment: You're mixing up client-side execution with the server-side script here.
You can validate if the passwords are identical in javascript on the client side. Later, re-check this on the server-side.
Edit: Just a bit too slow - Scott was faster ;)

Comment: But how I can re-check this on the server-side?

Comment: Check this problem in code  $message = 'Passwords dont match';

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) - you need to understand how server-side code (e.g. PHP) actually works - or rather why you can't update the client, dynamically, with PHP.

Comment: You already have the code in your example. On serverside, you have to check if `$_POST["pass"] == $_POST["pass_again"]`

Comment: Only single quat not allow use abow code

Comment: why not use [input:valid](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_valid.asp) css?

Comment: @Rachel Gallen it doesn't check, if the passwords are the same.

Comment: @Revivalo ah of course.. gotcha. Worth integrating on client side to check the fields are filled though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate on the server-side after they submit the form and want to change the look, you could set the `class` of the `input` elements as you write them out instead of trying to do it with Javascript afterwards.

Something like this..

```php
<?php
$class = ($_POST['pass'] == $_POST['pass_again']) ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
?>
<style>
    .valid {
        bakground-color: green;
    }
    .invalid {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<form method="post">
    <input class="<?php echo $class; ?>" type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
    <input class="<?php echo $class; ?>" type="password" name="pass_again" id="pass_again">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Please note I didn't validate that this code has no bugs but you should get the idea.